# PhoneGap (Cordova) + BlackBerry 10 QNX Build Issues with Ant

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I am experienced in building applications for the BlackBerry platform, and am currently trying to deploy a sample application with **PhoneGap (Cordova)** with BlackBerry WebWorks for the **BlackBerry 10 Beta (QNX)** without much success. I am following the instructions at the [PhoneGap Getting Started Guide for BlackBerry](https://github.com/ctetreault/incubator-cordova-docs/blob/master/docs/en/edge/guide/getting-started/blackberry/index.md) guide, linked from their [developer blog](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/11/phonegap-blackberry-10/).

At the sixth step of the mentioned guide above, I am getting some issues where the **org.apache.cordova** feature cannot be found, as well as all **blackberry.*** features:

```
D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample>ant qnx build
Buildfile: D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build.xml

qnx:

build:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: cordovaExample.bar

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 24 files to D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\www\js
      [zip] Building zip: D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\cordovaExample.zip

build:
     [exec]
     [exec] D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample>"C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.2.9\dependencies\node\node.exe" "C
:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.2.9\lib\bbwp.js" D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\cordovaExample.zip -o D:\
Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build
     [exec] [INFO]    Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]    Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [WARN]    Build ID set in config.xml [version], but no signing password was provided [-g]. Bar will be unsigned
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: org.apache.cordova
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.find
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.identity.phone
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.pim.Address
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.pim.Contact
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.io.file
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.utils
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.io.dir
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.app.event
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.system.event
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.widgetcache
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.media.camera
     [exec] [WARN]    Failed to find feature with id: blackberry.media.microphone
     [exec] [INFO]    Generating output files
     [exec] [INFO]    Info: Package created: D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\simulator\cordovaExample.bar
     [exec] [INFO]    Info: Package created: D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample\build\device\cordovaExample.bar
     [exec] [INFO]    BAR packaging complete

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds

D:\Work\Development\PhoneGap\workspace\sample>
```

Notice that the **org.apache.cordova** feature cannot be found, as well as all **blackberry.*** features.

Ignoring the warnings and deploying to the BB10 simulator results in this error: i.imgur.com/aUcPM.png

It should be noted that none of the warnings above or the error upon execution occurs when deploying for the PlayBook instead of BlackBerry 10.

It would be appreciated if any guidance can be given to help towards the resolution of this issue.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that these warnings can be ignored as it packages the bar file successfully. The blackberry.* features that can't be found seem to only be required for BlackBerry 7.0 and below. It should be safe to delete those blackberry.* features from the config.xml if deployment is solely for BB10, but it's better for it to be retained if it will also be deployed to lower versions.

As for the line org.apache.cordova, a poster in the official forums stated:

> I think the WebWorks packager tries to find org.apache.cordova in the WebWorks SDK folder to copy it into the bar file, while in reality org.apache.cordova already exists in your www folder which is also being copied into the bar file. (Nevertheless I still think this line is still needed to access the Cordova API on the device)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing warnings is because BlackBerry 10 doesn't support some of the 'blackberry.*' APIs, so it is simply skipping over them.  I believe this is unrelated to your screenshot.

How are you trying to access the contacts exactly, do you have any sample code?